# Cannot get HDP public repo in Ambari UI

Tags: docker, hadoop, ambari

I have cloned the following project 
https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-ambari.
I have successfully managed to make the 3 ambari-docker containers and now i am trying to select an HDP version through the Ambari UI.
My problem is that each time it tries to get a public repo the request returns with a `400 code(could not access base url)`.
I tried to curl a repo through the ambari-server container but it returns with `could not resolve host`.
I am running this inside a VM(Ubuntu 18.04) behind a company firewall.
I have no problem with curl inside the VM but it does not work in the container.

I have already tried whatever i could find on proxy editing for docker,ambari,yum,etc.. and since i am new to this i don't know what else to look for.

I expect to be able to choose a public repo to continue with the cluster installation wizard

Comment: That repo hasn't been maintained in years... And HDP and Ambari has been updated several times in the meantime. If you want to deploy in VMs, I would suggest Ansible instead. https://github.com/hortonworks/ansible-hortonworks

Answer (score 0):

For Ambari to communicate during setup with the hosts it deploys to and manages, certain ports must be open and available. The easiest way to do this is to temporarily disable iptables, as follows:

- systemctl disable firewalld
- service firewalld stop